# Print nested list in a format of "XX to XX"

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python so I have been trying to figure out how to print the following list in the format below. I have tried to get them through indexes but it doesn't seem to work out.

So I have a list of tuples that I need to print out in the following format:

```
1. A1 to B1
2. C1 to D2 , C1 to B2
```

This is the following list I have that I need to convert to that format.

```
[['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'A3', 'C1', 'F4', 'C1', 'G5', 'C1', 'H6'], ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2', 'E1', 'D2', 'E1', 'G3', 'E1', 'H4']]
```

Comment: Show the code you've tried maybe.

Comment: So... where's this list of [tuples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> tuples = [['A1', 'B1'], 
...           ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'C2'], 
...           ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2']]

>>> for i, sequence in enumerate(tuples, 1):
...     it = iter(sequence)
...     print(i, ', '.join('{} to {}'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(it, it))

1 A1 to B1
2 C1 to D2, C1 to B2, C1 to E3, C1 to C2
3 E1 to D1, E1 to F2
```

You must replace [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if number of elements in the list is odd:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest

>>> tuples = [['A1', 'B1', 'T1'], 
              ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'C2', 'Z1'],
              ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2']]

>>> for i, sequence in enumerate(tuples, 1):
...     it = iter(sequence)
...     print(i, ', '.join('{} to {}'.format(x, y) 
...                        for x, y in izip_longest(it, it, fillvalue='X'))

1 A1 to B1, T1 to X
2 C1 to D2, C1 to B2, C1 to E3, C1 to C2, Z1 to X
3 E1 to D1, E1 to F2
```

Comment: `it = iter(sequence); zip(it, it)` - that is cheeky. But presumably much lower overhead than an offset-by-one list slice.

Answer (score 2):

```
start_list = [['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'A3', 
             'C1', 'F4', 'C1', 'G5', 'C1', 'H6'], ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2', 'E1', 'D2',
             'E1', 'G3', 'E1', 'H4']]

for line, sublist in enumerate(start_list):
    pairs_list = [ (a + " to " + b) for (a, b) in zip(sublist, sublist[1:]) ]
    print str(line)+'.', ', '.join(pairs_list)
```

OK, enough dense advanced code only answers.

```
start_list = [['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'A3', 
             'C1', 'F4', 'C1', 'G5', 'C1', 'H6'], ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2', 'E1', 'D2',
             'E1', 'G3', 'E1', 'H4']]

#Loop over the inner lists, with a counter
for line_num, sublist in enumerate(start_list):

    # Build up a string to print with a line number and dot
    output = str(line_num) + '. '

    # Count through the list of pairs, step 2
    # skipping every other one
    for i in range(0, len(sublist), 2):
        # take the current and next sublist item, into the output string
        # and add a trailing comma and space, to give the form 
        # "A to B, "
        output += sublist[i] + " to " + sublist[i+1] + ", "

    # remove trailing comma after last pair in the line
    output = output.rstrip(', ')

    print output
```

e.g.

```
0. A1 to B1
1. C1 to D2, C1 to B2, C1 to E3, C1 to A3, C1 to F4, C1 to G5, C1 to H6
2. E1 to D1, E1 to F2, E1 to D2, E1 to G3, E1 to H4
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this for you will be to iterate over the inner lists using an index and an offset.

Something like this (not tested):

```
for j, inner in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    print(j, '.', sep='', end=' ')
    for i in range(0, len(inner)-1, 2):
        print(inner[i], 'to', inner[i+1], ',', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loop and list comprehension

This would also work for lists with odd elements

**Code:**

```
lst=[['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'A3', 'C1', 'F4', 'C1', 'G5', 'C1', 'H6','H5'], ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2', 'E1', 'D2', 'E1', 'G3', 'E1', 'H4']]
for count,line in enumerate(lst )  :
    print str(count)+" , ".join([" %s to %s" %(tuple((line[i:i+2]))) if i+1 <len(line) else "Single king %s"%(line[i])  for i in range(0,len(line),2)])
```

**Output:**

```
0 A1 to B1
1 C1 to D2 ,  C1 to B2 ,  C1 to E3 ,  C1 to A3 ,  C1 to F4 ,  C1 to G5 ,  C1 to H6 , Single king H5
2 E1 to D1 ,  E1 to F2 ,  E1 to D2 ,  E1 to G3 ,  E1 to H4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
>>> l = [['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'C1', 'E3', 'C1', 'A3', 'C1', 'F4', 'C1', 'G5', 'C1', 'H6'], ['E1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F2', 'E1', 'D2', 'E1', 'G3', 'E1', 'H4']]
>>>
>>>
>>> for i,m in enumerate(l):
...    print '%s. %s' %(i+1, ' , '.join([' to '.join(n) for n in zip(m[::2], m[1::2])]))
... 
1. A1 to B1
2. C1 to D2 , C1 to B2 , C1 to E3 , C1 to A3 , C1 to F4 , C1 to G5 , C1 to H6
3. E1 to D1 , E1 to F2 , E1 to D2 , E1 to G3 , E1 to H4
```